# Is there a difference in order of bean creation between dispatch servlet and context Loader Listener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I faced an issue when accessing an instance variable when configuration xml is loaded through context Loader Listener.

Below is a configuration xml for creating beans

```
<bean id="A" class"org.sample.A">       
</bean>

<bean id="B" class"org.sample.B">
  <property name="cobj" ref="C"/>
</bean>

<bean id="C" class"org.sample.C"/>
```

Below is the java code

```
 Class A{ 
    C cobj = null;
    public A(){
      cobj = B.getInstance().getCobj();
    }
    void display(){
      System.out.println(cobj);
    }
 } 
 Class B{ 
    private static bobj = null;
    C cobj = null;
    public static B getInstance(){
      if (bobj == null) {
         return new B();
      } 
      return bobj;
    }

    public setCobj(C obj){
      this.cobj = obj
    }
    public C getCobj(){
     return cobj;
    }
 }
 Class C{

 }
```

When the configuration xml is loaded through context Loader Listener , sysout prints null.
But when the same configuration is loaded through Dispatcher servlet the value is available.

Moreover if the display method is modified as below it shows result

```
public void display(){
      B stackObj = new B();
      System.out.println(stackObj.cobj);
   }
```

Bean B is initialized later when configured through context Loader.
But its initialized earlier of Class A if configured through dispatcher servlet.

Can this order of creation be determined ?

Comment: Use spring or don't why on earth are you using getInstance and creating beans in your context. Both are a bit contradicting.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. I removed those methods and initialized using spring . But i want to know why the order is different between dispatcher servlet and context loader.

Comment: There is no difference... The difference is due to the contraption with your `getInstance` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You dont create objects by yourself. This is what Spring is supposed to do; provide objects to you. Load all the objects by making a call to `xmlBeanFactory` and then you make actual use of **spring**.